# Как изменить значение в observable массиве?

Tags: reactjs, mobx

Есть наблюдаемый массив объектов в сторе:

`let example = observable([{b:100},{b:200,c:"abc"}])`

Использую mobx5. Для того, чтобы отрендерить компонент приходится прогонять массив через toJS(), и из-за этого не получается менять значение в массиве example напрямую.

Как получить ссылку на конкретный объект в массиве, при onClick в компоненте, чтобы изменить его?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я подготовил пример где можно подсмотреть как обновить данные объекта внутри **observable** массива.
Для того что бы mobx правильно отслеживал изменения, нужно:

1. задать **observable** для массива
2. задать **action.bound** для функций/действий которые будут обновлять наш **observable-массив**
3. Вызвать указанную выше функцию с правильными аргументами
4. Задать наши компоненты "наблюдателями" за изменениями используя **observer([название компоненты])**
5. Для того что бы найти нужный объект внутри массива, можно использовать `index` к которому есть доступ при `.map` когда строится/рендерится список компонентов. Его нужно передать в функцию-обработчик эвента, которая в свою очередь должна быть каррирована (возвратить функцию) и поставить локальное состояние с выбранным индексом - в примере это функция `selectRow`

[Пример исполнения CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/l583xyz45z)